# Adding Facebook Photos to Custom Feed

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to add a Facebook feed to a website and everything is working except I cannot get it to show photo statuses. This is what I have so far:

```
$page_id = 'xxxxxxxxx';
$access_token = 'xxxxxxx|xxxxxxxxxx';
//Get the JSON
$json_object = @file_get_contents('https://graph.facebook.com/' . $page_id . 
'/posts?access_token=' . $access_token);
//Interpret data
$fbdata = json_decode($json_object);


$i = 1;
foreach ($fbdata->data as $post )
{

if($i < 2){
$posts .= '<p><a href="' . $post->link . '">' . $post->story . '</a></p>';
$posts .= '<p><a href="' . $post->link . '">' . $post->message . '</a></p>';
$posts .= '<p>' . $post->description . '</p>';
$posts .= '<img src="'.$post->picture.'">';

}
$i++;
}

//Display the posts

echo $posts;

?>
```

Comment: What do you mean by `I cannot get it to show photo statuses` ?

Comment: Currently only text statuses will show if I post a photo on the Facebook feed it does not show up.

Comment: Try using `$post->picture`, this will return you the link of the picture if there is any.

Comment: I have added this
$posts .= '<p><a href="' . $post->link . '">' . $post->message . '</a></p>';
$posts .= $post->picture;
but no luck nothing shows still

Comment: I have updated my answer, this should work now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, to show the picture too, with your posts:

```
$page_id = 'xxxxxxxxx';
$access_token = 'xxxxxxx|xxxxxxxxxx';
//Get the JSON
$json_object = @file_get_contents('https://graph.facebook.com/' . $page_id . 
'/posts?access_token=' . $access_token . '&fields=id,link,message,picture,description,story');
//Interpret data
$fbdata = json_decode($json_object);

$i = 1;
foreach ($fbdata->data as $post )
{

if($i < 2){
//$posts .= '<p><a href="' . $post->link . '">' . $post->story . '</a></p>';
$posts .= '<p><a href="' . $post->link . '">' . $post->message . '</a><img src="'.$post->picture.'"></p>';
//$posts .= '<p>' . $post->description . '</p>';
//$posts .= '<br />';

}
$i++;
}
//Display the posts

echo $posts;
```

Comment: Thanks - but this doesn't seem to be working it is outputting a blank <img src="">

Comment: @Michelle In that case you will have to update your question with some of the data that you're getting in `$fbdata->data`, its really difficult to help you out without knowing the structure of the data that you're using.

Comment: Thanks - I have updated my code in the original question for you to see.

Comment: Which bit should I try? I have tried the original code you posted but no luck with it.

Comment: @Michelle I have updated my answer and have added `$json_object = @file_get_contents('https://graph.facebook.com/' . $page_id . 
'/posts?access_token=' . $access_token . '&fields=id,link,message,picture,description,story');`

Comment: @Michelle glad it helped you, could you up vote the answer, it will be helpful to someone if they have the same problem.

Comment: I am not sure I can as when I click the arrow it says I don't have enough reputation points.

Answer (score 0):

If you want photos

```
$photo = $news->picture;
$content .= "<img src='{$photo}'/>";
```

add this code

Comment: Sorry could you show how this would fit into my code?